# How to set an individual cookie time out for "Remember Me " at login process in Asp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, remember-me

I have a program in asp.net core and set a time out for application in startup file  with service Injection and i need to have a another cookie time Out just for my Remember Me option in Login Process, 
Anybody Know how to do it ?

I use  app.configureApplicationCookie() in startup file.
and don't know where and how could I have another cookie setting for just a "Remember Me" cookie

Answer (score 1):

this question`s answer in my application:
in REST Layer Startup file just add

```
app.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option=> {option.ExpireRimeSpan=TimeSpan.FromDays(10);})
```

in login page when you tick the Remember Me check Box ,the "Sign In Manager" prepare a cookie with expiration date of 10 days later and when you do not check the Remember Me check Box , the cookie act as normal in your Application.